# How should I solve this module not found error '__main __' is not a package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package, python-import

[image: This is my code]

This is my actual code saved as Cartoonify.py

This is my init.py

```
#init.py file

from .Cartoonify import Cartoon<br>
__all__= [
    "Cartoon"
]
```

I am getting this following error:
ModuleNotFoundError:
 No module named '__ main __.Cartoonify'; '__main __' is not a package

Answer (score 0):

If you try to import files from in a package with `.something`, this error always shows up. Your package needs to be run as package in order to work, so you should get a file outside the package, in which you do:

```py
import <package>

doSomethings()
```

That should work.

Comment: uh...I still didn't get this.